# Hamiltonian paths of the Hoffman-Singleton graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Does anyone know how many Hamiltonian paths of the [Hoffman-Singleton graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoffman%E2%80%93Singleton_graph) there are, or how I might go about figuring that out?

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know, the count is unknown.  Why do you want it?

The Odd-4 graph is a 35-vertex valence-4 subgraph, and it has 1419264 undirected Hamiltonian cycles, and 328345920 undirected Hamiltonian paths.  With more vertices and a higher valency, the number of paths will be much higher.

Comment: I've discovered some interesting connections between Moore graphs and some exceptional objects in mathematics recently, and one of those involves the Hamiltonian paths of the Peterson graph, and I'm curious if a similar result holds for Moore.  I'd be open to sharing moore of my ideas (pun intended) over email.

Comment: @KristapsJohnBalodis can you give an appetizer for moore?